Update a existing Firebase field with new data
Before update:

I want update the value of Plavix 75mg:"50". When user give a new value my code add a new value with a new ID instead of modifying the previous one. Here is the result:

Please help me to fix this.
Here is my code.

public class ViewPharmaceuticals extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout pharmaceuticalList;
    private FirebaseFirestore db;
    private String storeName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpharmaceuticals);

        pharmaceuticalList = findViewById(R.id.pharmaceuticalsList);
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        if (currentUser != null){
            String userId = currentUser.getUid();
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Pharmacists").child(userId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult().exists()){
                        storeName = task.getResult().child("storename").getValue(String.class);
                        loadPharmaceuticals();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(ViewPharmaceuticals.this, "Failed to retrieve your data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    private void loadPharmaceuticals(){
        if (storeName != null){
            CollectionReference storeCollection = db.collection(storeName);
            storeCollection.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        for (DocumentSnapshot document :task.getResult()){
                            Log.d("ViewPharmaceuticals", "Document: " + document.getData()); // Log the document data
                            displayPharmaceutical(document);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(ViewPharmaceuticals.this, "Error getting your information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    private void displayPharmaceutical(DocumentSnapshot document){
        View pharmaceuticalView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.pharmaceutical_item,pharmaceuticalList,false);
        TextView nameTextView = pharmaceuticalView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        TextView doseTextView = pharmaceuticalView.findViewById(R.id.doseTextView);
        TextView quantityTextView = pharmaceuticalView.findViewById(R.id.quantityTextView);
        Button editButton = pharmaceuticalView.findViewById(R.id.editButton);
        Button deleteButton = pharmaceuticalView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);

        nameTextView.setText(document.getString("drugName"));
        doseTextView.setText(document.getString("dose"));
        Object quantityObject = document.get("quantity");
        String quantityString;

        if (quantityObject instanceof Number) {
            quantityString = String.valueOf(((Number) quantityObject).longValue());
        } else if (quantityObject instanceof String) {
            quantityString = (String) quantityObject;
        } else {
            quantityString = "N/A";
        }

        quantityTextView.setText(quantityString);

        editButton.setOnClickListener(v -> showEditDialog(document));
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(v -> showDeleteDialog(document));
        pharmaceuticalList.addView(pharmaceuticalView);
    }
    private void showEditDialog(DocumentSnapshot document){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_pharmaceutical_dialog,null);
        builder.setView(dialogView);

        EditText doseEditText = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.doseEditText);
        EditText quantityEditText = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.quantityEditText);

        doseEditText.setText(document.getString("dose"));
        Object quantityObject = document.get("quantity");
        String quantityString;

        if (quantityObject instanceof Number) {
            quantityString = String.valueOf(((Number) quantityObject).longValue());
        } else if (quantityObject instanceof String) {
            quantityString = (String) quantityObject;
        } else {
            quantityString = "0"; // Fallback if quantity is not a Number or String
        }

        quantityEditText.setText(quantityString);

        builder.setTitle(document.getString("drugName"));
        builder.setPositiveButton("Update",(dialog,which)->{
            String newDose = doseEditText.getText().toString();
            String newQuantity = quantityEditText.getText().toString();
            updatePharmaceutical(document.getId(),newDose, newQuantity);
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",(dialog,which)-> dialog.dismiss());
        builder.create().show();
    }
    private void updatePharmaceutical(String documentId, String newDose, String newQuantity) {
        if (storeName != null) {
            CollectionReference storeCollection = db.collection(storeName);
            Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
            updates.put("dose", newDose);
            updates.put("quantity", newQuantity);
            storeCollection.document(documentId).update(updates)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully updated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateRealtimeDatabase(documentId, newQuantity); // Update Realtime Database with new quantity
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(this, "Error caught while updating document", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
        }
    }


    private void showDeleteDialog(DocumentSnapshot document){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Delete Pharmaceutical").setMessage("Do you want to delete the pharmaceutical?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",(dialog, which) -> deletePharmaceutical(document.getId()))
                .setNegativeButton("No",((dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss())).create().show();
    }
    private void deletePharmaceutical (String documentId){
        if (storeName != null){
            CollectionReference storeCollection = db.collection(storeName);
            storeCollection.document(documentId).delete().addOnSuccessListener(aVoid ->{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Pharmaceutical Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                reloadPharmaceuticals();
            }).addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(this, "Error caught deleting pharmaceutical. Please contact the administrator.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
        }
    }
    private void updateRealtimeDatabase(String drugName, String newQuantity) {
        FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            String userId = currentUser.getUid();
            DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Pharmacists").child(userId).child("drugData");

            // Update Realtime Database with new quantity for the corresponding drug
            userRef.child(drugName).setValue(newQuantity)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> Log.d("ViewPharmaceuticals", "Realtime Database updated with new quantity"))
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.e("ViewPharmaceuticals", "Error updating Realtime Database", e));
        }
    }

    private void reloadPharmaceuticals(){
        pharmaceuticalList.removeAllViews();
        loadPharmaceuticals();
    }
}

I want to modify the same value instead of adding a new field. I tried so many ways to do this but every attempt was useless.

The problem is here:
updateRealtimeDatabase(documentId, newQuantity)

Your documentId is the ID of the document in Firestore. What you want instead is to use the drug name:
updateRealtimeDatabase("Plavix 75mg", newQuantity)

If you don't want to hard-code the drug name (hint: you don't), you'll need to pass that into the call to updatePharmaceutical.

The thing is this part is used to update the real-time database. Another Java activity stores drug names and quantities in the real-time database while other drug details are saved in the FireStore. So, in this activity, I can update the values of Firestore but I cannot update the values of the real-time database. Is there any way to show you the full code? Email or something. I hope you will get a full idea by viewing the full code. Thank you for helping.

I updated to the full code. Now please tell me how to resolve that

I already understood the problem from the code you shared originally, and answered based on that. Did you try the change I showed in my answer? What did that do? Any error message? --- Also see What should I do when someone answers my question?

I couldn't solve this. So, instead of doing this what I did is when the user updates new data, I created a method to delete the old field and create a new field with a new quantity. Now the function works perfectly. Thank you Mr. Puffelen for your assistance and your humbleness.
